# Dafny linked queue implementation

Tags: linked-list, verification, dafny

I'm following Leino's paper "Specification and verification of OO software" and trying to implement the queue example. I'm unable to resolve an (syntax?) error that comes while defining the valid predicate in the `Queue` class.

My code looks like this:

```
class Node {
    var data: int
    var next: Node?

    var tailContents: seq<int>
    var footprint: set<object>

    predicate valid()
        reads this, footprint
    {
        this in footprint &&
        (next != null ==> next in footprint && next.footprint <= footprint) &&
        (next == null ==> tailContents == []) &&
        (next != null ==> tailContents == [next.data] + next.tailContents)
    }

    constructor()
        modifies this
        ensures valid() && fresh(footprint - {this})
        ensures next == null
    {
        next := null;
        tailContents := [];
        footprint := {this};
    }
}

class Queue {
    var head: Node?
    var tail: Node?

    var contents: seq<int>
    var footprint: set<object>
    var spine: set<Node>

    predicate valid()
        reads this, footprint
    {
        this in footprint && spine <= footprint &&
        head != null && head in spine &&
        tail != null && tail in spine &&
        tail.next == null && 
        (forall n | n in spine :: n != null && n.valid())
.......
    }
```

I get an error

> Insufficient reads clause to invoke function

at `n.valid()`. I'm unsure if this is a syntax error or there is something I'm missing. I know that the paper is quite old and there may be some changes required to the code.

Comment: Can you paste full code. Definition of Node etc are missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is condition missing in `valid` predicate of Queue. That is node footprint is subset of queue footprint. In original version, Queue class can only read objects from its footprint. But then it calls node `valid` predicate where it need to read node footprint. Unless we say that Queue class can read node footprints it will complain. But here solution is simpler as node footprint will be subset of Queue footprint.

```
predicate valid()
    reads this, footprint
{
    this in footprint && spine <= footprint &&
    head != null && head in spine &&
    tail != null && tail in spine &&
    tail.next == null &&
    (forall n | n in spine :: n.footprint <= footprint) &&
    (forall n | n in spine :: n.valid())
}
```

---

Edit : Paper also has this in its valid, I think you have missed it[image]

Comment: Yes, its here in the paper too. The problem is the ordering of the statements, In my predicate, I check "n != null && n.Valid()" first. Since it was giving me an error, I didn't bother to write "n.footprint <= footprint" in the predicate.

Comment: Ah, probably order didn't mattered in earlier versions of dafny. It do now it seems